# no suitable constructor found for PrintWriter(File, boolean)

Tags: java, printwriter

```
File file = new File("output.txt");

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file,true);
```

When I use `PrintWriter(file,true)` it's show me error

> "no suitable constructor found for PrintWriter(File, boolean)"

how to solve it ,Thanks

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc? You can't just make things up and then wonder why they don't exist.

Comment: @Tom Possible duplicate how?

Comment: @EJP OP _clearly_ wants to instantiate a `PrintWriter` which appends to an existing source and the answers there tell him how to do so.

Comment: @Tom That is a rather large assumption as the constructors on `PrintWriter` that do take a boolean enable auto-flush.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that's true, but I don't think OP was aiming for that. I could be wrong there, though. So it isn't that "clearly" on second thought.

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` class doesn't have a constructor that accepts `File, Boolean`

Your best bet is to remove the `Boolean`, and just pass the `File`.

See full list taken from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

```
PrintWriter(File file) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file.

PrintWriter(File file, String csn) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file and charset.

PrintWriter(OutputStream out) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream.

PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) 
Creates a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream.

PrintWriter(String fileName) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file name.

PrintWriter(String fileName, String csn) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file name and charset.

PrintWriter(Writer out) 
Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing.

PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush) 
Creates a new PrintWriter.
```

Answer (score 0):

PrintWriter class does not have any constructor that take 2 parameter File and boolean together.

So You have to remove boolean parameter.and write code as-

```
File file = new File("output.txt");

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
```